# For overdispered data, should the correlation matrix exclude zero?

Tags: correlation, negative-binomial-distribution, pearson-r, overdispersion

I have 4 species and their distributions are overdispersed in space (i.e. lots of zeros). I calculated a Pearson correlation matrix and there is a lot of cluster around the 0s and 1s. Should I eliminate the 0s from the data to calculate the correlation? Or should I use something other than Pearson for overdispered data?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since your data are clearly not normally distributed, Spearman's correlation coefficient will perform much better than Pearson's.

Comment: But should I be excluding the zeros first and then running the correlation?

Comment: No. Spearman's correlation doesn't make any assumpions on the distribution of variables, so large number of zeros is not a problem for it.